# с# Разбить строку с цифрами на часы и минуты

Tags: c#, числа

Как сделать что бы функция  брала из textBox числа, например текс textbox = 8:50, 8 - это час, 50 - минуты, заносила это всё в разные переменные, например:
hour = 8
minute = 50
и потом находила время, пример:
time = 8 * 60 + minute
и как это засунуть в цикл, что бы для каждого textBox были свои переменные hour minute time

Comment: Не изобретайте велосипед, используйте уже готовые механизмы. `var time = TimeSpan.Parse("8:50");`, все, у вас готовы все данные, хотите минуты - `time.Minutes`, хотите часы - `time.Hours`, ну а хотите сколько всего минут - `time.TotalMinutes`.

Comment: А если я хочу что бы в переменную time вносились данные с textbox? Типо так? var time = TimeSpan.Parse(textBox1.Text);

Comment: да, именно так.

Comment: Если нужно вводить время, то используйте `DateTimePicker` вместо `TextBox`. Тогда не придётся ничего парсить.

Comment: Alexander Petrov, но мне нужно использовать именно текст из TextBox, что и я указал в условии. EvgeniyZ, а если я хочу всунуть эту строку в цикл var time = TimeSpan.Parse(textBox1.Text); что бы значения бокса увеличивались на 1, как мне это сделать?

Comment: Нет, вам не нужно использовать текст из TextBox. Вы, как разработчик, должны предоставить пользователю возможность удобно вводить значения времени.